# acces a local variable outside anonymous function (jquery, javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a variable outside an anonymous function.
Not declaring it as var in the function should make it's scope global but it doesnt work in this case. I think you have to call the function first but how do i call this function? PS: I'm just learning js. Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       x = position.coords.latitude;
       y = position.coords.longitude;
    });

console.log(x);}); //end of ready
```

Comment: I removed java tag

Comment: _Not declaring it as var in the function should make it's scope global_ - no it shouldn't. Use `window.x` to declare this var in global scope.

Comment: @31piy: Actually, it does, in loose mode, if you assign to it as in the above. It creates an *implicit global*. See my blog post: [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Could you just explain why this is a duplicate of the question about async returns? Its not obvious that there is anything async here.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat: [`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition) is an async operation, that's why it provides its information in a callback. Even if we didn't have docs for it, we could infer that, since If it weren't async it wouldn't make sense to do that; you'd just return `position` instead.

Comment: Thanks @T.J.Crowder - helpful for future readers.